# Contact Form 7 Hook for skip_mail

Tags: wordpress, paypal, contact-form-7

I am getting stacked with Contact Form 7 and PayPal & Stripe Add-on (for Contact Form 7) plugins.
On Contact Form 7, I turn on additional setting `skip_mail = on`.
Is it possible to create a hook to turn `skip_mail = off` and sending the data from the form when people already paid the payment in the PayPal & Stripe Add-on plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line of code.

```
/*
    Prevent the email sending step for specific form and condition 
*/
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");  
function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {
    // get the contact form object
    $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    // if you wanna check the ID of the Form $wpcf->id

    if (/*Check whether user already paid the payment in the PayPal & Stripe Add-on plugin*/) {
        // If you want to skip mailing the data, you can do it...  
        $wpcf->skip_mail = true;    
    }

    return $wpcf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail', function( $skip_mail, $contact_form ){
    $skip = ( $contact_form->id() == 111 ) // skip send mail if cf7_id = 111
    return $skip; // return true or false
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Please add comment to your code and explain how it work

Comment: Explained here http://hookr.io/filters/wpcf7_skip_mail/

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference in case the target page is unavailable or changes.